# Jenkins Shared library groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method

Tags: class, librería, jenkins, groovy

Estoy tratando de crear una shared library de jenkins para poder compartir varios metodos y funciones entre pipelines

El problema ocurre cuando trato de llamar a jsonSlurper desde una clase que cree pasandole un parametro de tipo String desde el pipeline (Jenkins file declarativo)

Este es el error que arroja:

> hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No
> signature of method: static groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parseText() is
> applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [{
> "resource": [] }] Possible solutions: parseText(java.lang.String), parse([B), parse([C), parse(java.io.File), parse(java.io.InputStream),
> parse(java.io.Reader)     at
> groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1501)
> at
> groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1487)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaClassSite.call(StaticMetaClassSite.java:53)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
> at
> com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
> at
> org.dtv.automation.terraform.TerraformResources.loadTemplate(TerraformResources.groovy:29)
> at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:181)   at
> ***cps.transform***(Native Method)    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:86)
> at
> com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
> at
> com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor333.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
> at
> com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.LocalVariableBlock$LocalVariable.get(LocalVariableBlock.java:39)
> at
> com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
> at
> com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.LocalVariableBlock.evalLValue(LocalVariableBlock.java:28)
> at
> com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$BlockImpl.eval(LValueBlock.java:55)
> at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock.eval(LValueBlock.java:16)   at
> com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)  at
> com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)     at
> com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)     at
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
> at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
> at
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
> at
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
> at
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
> at
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:400)
> at
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
> at
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:312)
> at
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:276)
> at
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:136)
> at
> jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
> at
> jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Esta es la porcion de codigo del jenkinsfile que falla:

```
def resources = new TerraformResources()
resources.loadTemplate(libraryResource('templates/terraform-resource.json').toString())

disks.eachWithIndex{ disk, index->

    volume = new TerraformVolume()
    volume.loadTemplate(libraryResource('templates/terraform-volume-template.json').toString())
    volume.setName(disk.label)
    volume.setDisplay_name('volume-${var.hostname}-${var.disks['+index+'].label}')
    volume.setSize_in_gbs('${var.disks['+index+'].size}')

    resources.addResource(getVolumeObject())
    }
```

Estsas son las definiciones de mis 2 clases:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
package org.dtv.automation.terraform
import groovy.transform.InheritConstructors
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper 
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

      
    
    private Object resourcesObject
        
    private Object getResourcesObject() {

        return this.resourcesObject

    }
    
    public void addResource(Object resource ){
        
        this.resourcesObject.resource.add(resource)
    }

    public String getResourceJson(){ 
        
        JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(resourcesObject))

    }
    public void loadTemplate(template){

         this.resourcesObject = JsonSlurper.parseText(template)

    }




return this
```

and

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
package org.dtv.automation.terraform
import groovy.transform.InheritConstructors
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper 
import groovy.json.JsonOutput


    
    private String name
    private String display_name
    private String size_in_gbs
    private Object attributes

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDisplay_name() {
        return this.display_name;
    }

    public void setDisplay_name(String display_name) {
        this.display_name = display_name;
    }

    public String getSize_in_gbs() {
        return this.size_in_gbs;
    }

    public void setSize_in_gbs(String size_in_gbs) {
        this.size_in_gbs = size_in_gbs;
    }


    
    public void loadTemplate(template){
        
        this.attributes = JsonSlurper.parseText(template)
    }

    
    public Object getVolumeObject(){

        this.attributes.display_name = this.display_name
        this.attributes.size_in_gbs = this.size_in_gbs 

        def Object volume = Object.put("oci_core_volume",[Object.put(name,[attributes])])

    }
    



return this
```

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar con esto.

Mychas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Gracias, ya lo puse en español. Mil disculpas

Comment: Tengo un código parecido pero hay dos cosas que pudieran pasar. La primera es que no tienes creado el objeto JsonSlurper. Lo otro es que debes verificar que el objeto que le estes pasando al parseText sea un string. Lo que creo que está pasando es que el resultado de libraryResource no es un string. Imprimelo a ver que trae

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, he logrado ejecutar un work arround dejando de usar el json slurper, parece que la implementación a nivel groovy no es la misma que la del pipeline, por eso lo tipos de objetos no coinciden. Al final usando los steps readJson y json output pude hacer lo que necesitaba.

Comment: En la versión de Jenkins (no recuerdo la versión, pero era la última LTS de hace un par de meses) funcionaba con el jsonSlurper. El código era muy parecido al que usaste, por eso no lo subí. De todas maneras si necesitas el código avísame y lo monto

Comment: Si quires montalo, ayudaría a entender que estaba haciendo mal.